# How to pass Model value from Test class to Action Method in Controller class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, testing, nunit, nsubstitute

I am creating some Nunit tests for an MVC application. I am writing a test case for a methods in my Controller class. I am using Nsubstitute for Mocking the object.

I am learning about Nunit and Nsubstitue and I don't know, how to pass my Model value which was mocked in the testcase method to my controller method.

Below is my method in the controller class:

```
public ActionResult Manage(string id)
{
    var clusterCollections = ReadXml();
    int clusterIndex = clusterCollections.ClusterCollectionList.FindIndex(a => a.ClusterId == id);
    var model = new ClusterManagementModel()
    {
        ClusterNodeDetailsList = BindClusterDetailsToGrid(id),
        DropDownListClusterName = BindClusterNameToDropDown(),
        CurrentClusterId = clusterIndex,
        CurrentClusterName = id,
        HStatus = Hstatus(id),
        IStatus = Istatus(id)
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

This is the TestCase I have written:

```
[TestCase]
public void TestManage()
{         
    var ManagementController = Substitute.ForPartsOf<ClusterManagementController>();
    var ManagementModel = Substitute.ForPartsOf<ClusterManagementModel>();
    ClusterCollections clusterCollection = new ClusterCollections();
    List<ClusterNodeDetails> ClusterNodes = new List<ClusterNodeDetails>();
    List<DDL_ClusterName> DropDownListClusterName = new List<DDL_ClusterName>();
    ManagementController.ReadXml().Returns(clusterCollection);
    ManagementModel = new ClusterManagementModel()
    {
        ClusterNodeDetailsList = ClusterNodes,
        DropDownListClusterName = DropDownListClusterName,
        CurrentClusterId = 1,
        CurrentClusterName = "UnitTesting",
        HStatus = "True",
        IStatus = "Success"
    };
    var result = ManagementController.Manage("1") as ActionResult;
    Assert.AreEqual(ManagementModel, result);
}
```

If I have made mistakes in the TestCase Method please correct me.

If my TestCase is wrong, can you give me a suggestion how to write a TestCase for the above method `(public ActionResult Manage(string id))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know, how to pass Model value

The short answer is that in its current form, you can't pass the model you've created in your test to your controller.  This is a common problem that people run into when they first start trying to unit test their code.  The way out of the hole is to start writing your production code with testing in mind.

One approach that is common is to extract dependencies from your class and to inject these dependencies through the constructor for the class.  So, you might extract your model creation logic into a `ModelFactory` and modify your controller to have a constructor like this:

```
public ManagementController(IModelFactory modelFactory) {
    _modelFactory = modelFactory;
}
```

There are various libraries that can help to inject these dependencies (Ninject, AutoFac etc).  But if you don't want to / can't use them, then you will also need to add a default constructor that sets up your dependencies to default concrete implementations:

```
public ManagementController() {
    _modelFactory = new ModelFactory();
}
```

This allows you to create Stubbed / Mocked / Substituted implementations of IModelFactory and inject it into your controller / other class under test.  So, your test might start off something like this:

```
List<ClusterNodeDetails> ClusterNodes = new List<ClusterNodeDetails>();
List<DDL_ClusterName> DropDownListClusterName = new List<DDL_ClusterName>();

var model = new ClusterManagementModel()
{
    ClusterNodeDetailsList = ClusterNodes,
    DropDownListClusterName = DropDownListClusterName,
    CurrentClusterId = 1,
    CurrentClusterName = "UnitTesting",
    HStatus = "True",
    IStatus = "Success"
};

var modelFactory = Substitute.For<IModelFactory>();
modelFactory.CreateClusterManagementModel( /* args for model creation */).Returns(model);

var sut = new ManagementController(modelFactory);
var result = sut.Manage("1") as ActionResult;
```

You also need to think about what it is you're trying to test.  By extracting the dependencies you're able to focus on the logic in your controller and focus your tests on that logic.  It's very easy when you start using Mocks to get into a situation where you're not actually testing anything at all, other than whether or not you've set your Mocks up correctly.  Remember, they are there to help you reproduce specific scenarios you need to force your production code to follow a particular flow, not to replace the logic contained in your production code.

Comment: @SureshRam You may also want to have a look at these as a good starting point:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942838.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff847525(v=vs.100).aspx